# How to make a random image generator that creates 2 images VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm doing a final project in action researh.I want to create a game that can improve students' speaking skills.

I have a PowerPoint slide with different images. I need to create VBA code in PowerPoint that pressing a button or clicking an object will randomly output two images. But we don't know VBA very well and have this so far from finding things online. It creates one image but I want to know how to make it display two at a time.

```vb
Sub RandomImage()

  Randomize

  RanNum% = Int(57 * Rnd) + 1

  Path$ = ActivePresentation.Path

  FullFileName$ = Path$ + "/" + CStr(RanNum%) + ".png"
  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FullFileName$, LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=500).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for`-loop.

You will have to think about a logic for the left-Parameter so that both pictures occure next to each other - please see my suggestion in the code

```
Sub RandomImage()

Dim i As Long
Dim posLeft As Long
  
For i = 1 To 2

    Randomize
  
    RanNum% = Int(57 * Rnd) + 1
  
    Path$ = ActivePresentation.Path
  
    FullFileName$ = Path$ + "/" + CStr(RanNum%) + ".png"
  
    posLeft = 100 + ((i-1) * 510)   '-->>> you will have to adjust this to your needs
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FullFileName$, LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=posLeft, Top:=100, Width:=500).Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me. It works when I test from runsub.
But when I test from  Present slideshows , it can't press to random. 
I uploaded the image in the link. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1njHkRQ5FpdnjG101KLAn8cntPoFWxX1Z?usp=sharing
Thank you

Comment: Sorry - it's hard to tell: did you map the button to the sub? I haven't done that in powerpoint - but there has to be an onClick-event or so.

Comment: If you want it to work in slide show view, you'll have to remove .SELECT at the end of the line that adds the image; you can't select things in slide show view, so this will fail. To make the code run when you click a shape, select the shape, choose Insert | Action and choose Run Macro: RandomImage as the action to run when the shape is clicked.

Comment: All of you guys, I really thank you.
I'cant remove ".SELECT "  at the end of the line. So I added Insert | Action and choose Run Macro: RandomImage but it only runs one image at a time.
So I added the subs on this site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.actionsettings) . but randomly only get one picture at a time as before.
I don't know where it's wrong. I am new to VBA and trying to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All of you guys, I really thank you. I'cant remove ".SELECT " at the end of the line. So I added Insert | Action and choose Run Macro: RandomImage but it only runs one image at a time. So I added the subs on this site (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/…) . but randomly only get one picture at a time as before. I don't know where it's wrong. I am new to VBA and trying to learn. Thank you.

```
Sub Shape_Click()
    Set myShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
    myShape.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = ppActionLastSlide
    myShape.ActionSettings(ppMouseOver).SoundEffect.Name = "applause"
End Sub

Sub RandomImage()
     Dim i As Long
     Dim posLeft As Long
     For i = 1 To 2
     Randomize
     RanNum% = Int(57 * Rnd) + 1
     Path$ = ActivePresentation.Path
     FullFileName$ = Path$ + "/" + CStr(RanNum%) + ".png"
     posLeft = 100 + ((i - 1) * 510)
     ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FullFileName$, 
     LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=posLeft, Top:=100, 
     Width:=500).Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: >>  I'cant remove ".SELECT " at the end of the line. 
Why not?  Apart from that, what happens when you compile your current code?

Comment: After I remove "Select". it says "Compile.Error Expected = "

Comment: Ah, of course. SO either remove the parentheses surrounding Filename: ...Width:=500 OR leave it as is and add CALL to the beginning of the line:  CALL ActivePresentation....

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help ❤

Comment: If this is some additional information about your issue, add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I have a few questions ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ
If I want to create a random order to select another pair from my image. , not repeating the random pair you've previously picked, i.e. so that once you've gone through 56 random unique images i.e. 26 random pairs, the game is over, or you reset to your original 57 images and start picking random pairs again. Can this be done in VBA Powerpoint?